# How to evaluate custom parenthesis expression with pipe

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm, parsing

I have expression which looks like:

```
((type file1.csv file2.csv | Test +) & (type file3.csv file4.csv | Test +)) | Test + |Test sum | Test transpose | Test sum
```

The expression has many nested parenthesis and other special characters like

```
|
&
```

I want to evaluate the expression above in C# in this order:

```
1. (type file1.csv file2.csv | Test +)
2. (type file3.csv file4.csv | Test +)
3. 1 & 2 | Test +
4. 3 | Test sum
5. 4 | Test transpose
6. 5 | Test sum
```

I have referred to the sample solution shown here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36788281/4177530) using the Regex as below: `\(([^()]*)\)`

How do I modify the regex above to consider `|` and `&`?

Thank you

Comment: What about [`(?<!\([^)]*)[|&]`?](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%28%5b%5e%29%5d*%29%5b%7c%26%5d&i=%28%28type+file1.csv+file2.csv+%7c+Test+%2b%29+%26+%28type+file3.csv+file4.csv+%7c+Test+%2b%29%29+%7c+Test+%2b+%7cTest+sum+%7c+Test+transpose+%7c+Test+sum%0d%0a) Not sure what you mean otherwise...

Comment: Parsing algebraic expressions cannot be done with one Regex pattern.  You have to follow algebraic rules so you properly parse correctly following hierarchical rules.

Comment: @jdweng, what solution do you propose to parse the expression?

Comment: It really would help if you explained what “to evaluate the expression” means. Do you want to return a list or something of strings? You want to do something with each string?

Comment: I Wasn't proposing a solution.  Just indicating the proposed solution won't work.  See wiki for correct way of parsing using grammar : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar

Comment: @Dour_high_arch, "to evaluate the expression" means I want to return a list of string (order of string in the list) matters. I want to evaluate each list element in the list as shown in my original post (no 1 to no 6)